# WPF share resourcedictionaries among controls

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have 2 dictionaries merged in my WPF app (base dict merged with skin dict).
It works very fine on the MainWindow, but when I added a new WPF Window, it seems unable to access the StaticResource.

This is the code of the new Window:

```
<Window x:Class="Sc2ReplayMonkey.PleaseWaitWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sc2ReplayMonkey"
        Title="PleaseWaitWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource WindowBackground}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource WindowTextelement}" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            Please wait while the replays            
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            are parsed and serialized
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I get the error "Cannot find the resource named "WindowBackground".
It is defined in the skin dict as:

```
<Style x:Key="WindowBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Have you added your rec. dictionary to Application Resources? Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resources);

Comment: In MainWindow yes, but not in PleaseWaitWindow.

Comment: This solved the problem, I simply added a line in PleaseWaitWindow's constructor: Resources = main.Resources; main being the MainWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem, I simply added a line in PleaseWaitWindow's constructor: Resources = main.Resources; main being the MainWindow

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add

```
 Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resources);
```

in you App.cs class once f.e in Initialize() method. Then your dictionary will be accessible from any windows.

Comment: if skins may change at runtime your skin dict class has to notify about it. I'm talking here about global access to the resource from all XAML code.